# Printing unicode characters from codes contained in variable and from file

Tags: perl, utf-8

Here's some code that doesn't do what I'm hoping it to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w 
use utf8;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

# open a filehandle to a file that contains a single line of text: Hello \x{2744}!
open (H, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", "test.txt") || die $!;
while(<H>) {
    $line = $_;
    chomp($line);
    $var = "Hello \x{2744}!";
    $line = $line . " $var\n";

    print STDOUT "$line";
}
```

The output is as follows:

```
Hello \x{2744}! Hello ❄!
```

Why does it print the contents of the variable I'm assigning in the script as unicode character but does not do the same with the text that is contained in the file?

I guess I'm missing something obvious - any pointers welcome!

Comment: That looks correct. Did you expect backslash sequences in the file be evaluated?

Comment: But it's not what I would like to see. I would like to have the value of $line also to be "translated" into the unicode character...

Comment: Both the initial value of $line and $var are the same. Why do they print differently once combined?

Answer (score -1):

Lines read from file have Unicode character *hex representation* but not character itself (byte sequence representing the character).

The line require to replace Unicode character *hex representation* with the character itself.

Following code snippet demonstrates two ways to achieve desired output.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
#
# vim: ai:ts=4:sw=4
#

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Encode;
use utf8;

binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

my @lines = (
    "Hello \x{2744}!",
    "Hello ❄!"
    );

while(my $line0=<DATA>) {
    chomp $line0;
    my $line1 = $line0;
    $line0 =~ s/\\x\{([\da-z]+)\}/decode('UTF-16',pack('H4',$1))/ieg;
    $line1 =~ s/\\x\{([\da-z]+)\}/chr(hex($1))/ieg;
    push @lines, $line0;
    push @lines, $line1;
}

say for @lines;

__DATA__
Hello \x{2744} you need \x{2602} to go under \x{2600}
Danger \x{2622} doctor Robinson, danger \x{2622}
```

Output

```
Hello ❄!
Hello ❄!
Hello ❄ you need ☂ to go under ☀
Hello ❄ you need ☂ to go under ☀
Danger ☢ doctor Robintson, danger ☢
Danger ☢ doctor Robintson, danger ☢
```